# How to calculate the average shareholder's equity?

Tags: financial-statements, ratio

We get the conclusion from a website:
[ROE and ASE](https://www.accountingtools.com/articles/average-shareholders-equity.html#:%7E:text=How%20to%20Calculate%20Average%20Shareholders%E2%80%99%20Equity%20The%20average,information%20is%20found%20on%20a%20company%E2%80%99s%20balance%20sheet.)
The average shareholders' equity calculation is the beginning shareholders' equity plus the ending shareholders' equity, divided by two. The resulting formula is:

```
(Beginning shareholders' equity + Ending shareholders' equity) ÷ 2 = Average shareholders’ equity
```

The concept may be built directly into the return on equity formula, where the average is stated in the denominator, as follows:

```
Net income ÷ ((Beginning shareholders' equity + ending shareholders' equity) ÷ 2) = Return on equity
```

Take `aapl`'s financial statements as an example:
I download and format the raw data (delete  items unrelated with the roe calculate ) as below:

income statement  [income](https://stockanalysis.com/stocks/aapl/financials/)

```
+------------------------------+--------+--------+
| year                         | 2022   | 2021   |
+------------------------------+--------+--------+
| net income                   | 99803  | 94680  |
+------------------------------+--------+--------+
```

balance statement  [balance-sheet](https://stockanalysis.com/stocks/aapl/financials/balance-sheet/)

```
+------------------------------+---------+---------+
| year                         | 2022    | 2021    |
+------------------------------+---------+---------+
| common stock                 | 64849   | 57365   |
+------------------------------+---------+---------+
| retained earnings            | -3068   | 5562    |
+------------------------------+---------+---------+
| comprehensive income         | -11109  | 163     |
+------------------------------+---------+---------+
| shareholders' equity         | 50672   | 63090   |
+------------------------------+---------+---------+
```

main ratios [ratios](https://stockanalysis.com/stocks/aapl/financials/ratios/)

```
+--------------------------+---------+---------+
| year                     | 2022    | 2021    |
+--------------------------+---------+---------+
| return on equity (roe)   | 160.90% | 144.10% |
+--------------------------+---------+---------+
```

We get all numbers to calculate roe on 2022:

```
Net income = 99803  (2022)
Beginning shareholders' equity =  63090 (2021)
ending shareholders' equity = 50672  (2022)

Return on equity on 2022 = Net income ÷ ((Beginning shareholders' equity + ending shareholders' equity) ÷ 2)
                         = 99803 ÷ ((63090+50672) ÷ 2)
                         = 175%
```

And  99803/50672 = 197%.
How can the webpage say aapl's roe on 2022 is 160.90% ?

Answer (score 1):

The average equity is the four continious quarter `shareholders' equity`,the concept of ttm.
For aapl's  2022 year 3 quarter:

```
average equity = (50.67+58.11+67.4+71.93)/4 = 62.0275
roe = net income /average equity = 99.80/62.0275 = 1.609
```